# Sierra 10.12.6 incremental update caught in reboot loop

Tags: macos, software-update, reboot

I have automatic updates turned on.

This morning I was prompted to reboot in order to install a new (incremental) update. However each time I reboot I get the Apple logo + installation progress bar that takes about 15 minutes to complete.

[image]

[image]

Clicking "UPDATE" forces a reboot but fails to advance the situation. I've tried twice. I've also tried a plain old reboot twice.

How to resolve?

Comment: EDIT: A couple more reboots seem to have sorted it out! I will leave the question in case anyone else starts questioning their sanity after three reboots.

Comment: I am in the same boat. 5 days. Visits to Genius bar......6 time machine rebuilds and the Apple Logo again and again. My advice DONT UPDATE. Wait. I have given up. Clearly a bug.

Comment: same here exactly. pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

Download the [ComboUpdate 10.12.6](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1931) (direct d/l link: [macOS Sierra 10.12.6 Combo Update](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1931/en_US/macosupdcombo10.12.6.dmg)). Open the downloaded dmg and launch the pkg file inside. Reboot when asked.

---

Alternate solution: clearing the App Store cache often seems to fix the problem.

1. Quit the App Store
2. Open Terminal
3. Run `open $TMPDIR../C/com.apple.appstore/`
4. Delete all contents in that folder
5. Open the App Store again and wait for it to check for updates

Comment: I have done as you described but no Joy... This results in the same loop and does not clear the update. The OS is showing as the version it wants to update to??? Broken Mac OS update.